# Differences in Processing when using java, javascript, and running embedded using processing.js

Tags: java, javascript, global-variables, processing, fill

I wrote some code to create a dynamic paintbrush, that changes colour, in Processing environment. The same code produces very different results when running in Java, Javascript and embedded javascript.

As far as i can tell there is no difference in handling of global variables in the different modes. also i am defining the color mode so even if there is differences, my definition should replace these. Any ideas?

I have a global float variable that i increment to cycle through the colours. (colours in HSB mode) 
I also draw a black rectanlge on the whole screen with very low alpha value in order to slowly fade out the drawings.

```
float cH = 0;
float cS = 0;
float cB = 0;
int counter = 0;
// other variables.... 

setup()
{
    size(800,600);
    colorMode(HSB, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    cH = 0.0;
    cS = 0.74;
    cB = 0.6;
    counter = 0;
    background(0);
    // .. other setup code
}

// ... other code

mouseDragged()
{   
   counter ++;
   if(counter %5 == 0)  {    
        noStroke();
        fill(0,0.01);
        rect(0,0, width, height);
    }

   cH += 1/500;

    if(cH >= 1.0)
       cH = 0.0;
    stroke(color( cH, cS, cB));
    fill(color( cH, cS, cB));

    //... then the code for drawing the shapes
}
```

This works beautifully when running it in processing, in javascript mode. See picture 1 below, working with colour change and fade out
[image: java]
When running this same sketch, embedded in my browser using javascript, the colour change works, but rectangles drawn on top turn grey instead of black. With the same colour values!
[image: embedded javascript]
you can try it out [here](http://processingsketches.appspot.com/trig)

#
When running it in java mode, the fade out to black works, but the color change doesnt. the brush stays its initial color, red.
[image]

The entire code, processing.pde file can be found [here](http://processingsketches.appspot.com/sketches/trig/trig.pde).

On my appengine I load the sketch from a html file as follows: With previous problems I made sure i was using the newest version of processing.js

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{name}} Sketch</title>
    <script src="/statics/processing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
    <script src="/statics/javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   

</head>

  <body>
      <label>Title</label>
      <br>
      <div class="proc">
      <canvas id="SKETCH" data-processing-sources="/sketches/{{name}}/{{name}}.pde" >   
  </canvas>
    <br>
    this is below the canvas
  </body>   
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of integer division at line `cH += 1/500;` JS has no such a thing...

from: http://processingjs.org/articles/p5QuickStart.html

> Division which is expected to produce an integer might need explicit casting
>   There are a class of bugs that arise when converting Processing code to Processing.js that involve integer vs. floating point division. What was straight-up integer division in Processing code, when converted to Processing.js, can sometimes become problematic, as numbers become doubles, and introduce a fractional part. The fix is to explicitly cast any division to an integer that exhibits this behaviour:

```
 // before
 int g = mouseX / i;

 // after
 int g = (int)(mouseX / i);
```

Comment: Interesting thanks, and i'll keep it in mind for future programs, but in this case cH is a float, and changing it to ""cH = (float)( cH + 1.0/500 );"" made no difference!

Comment: ops, sorry I missed ch was a float.